# What is the difference between a sentence starting with “the percentage” vs only a percentage?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, singular-vs-plural, ambiguity

Do these two sentences have the same meaning?

1. “98% of people who know about Hippos would agree that they’re the deadliest land animal
2. “The 98% of people who know about hippos would agree that they’re the deadliest land animal”

Comment: 1. 98 percent _of the people who know about hippos_ would agree... 2. 98% _of all the people in the world_ would agree... Obviously not the same meaning. All because of the definite article starting sentence (2).

Answer (score 0):

No, these two sentences do not have the same meaning.

The first could be rephrased like this: *Out of all of the people who know about hippos (whatever portion of the total population that might be), 98% of them believe that hippos are...*

The second could be rephrased like this: *98% of people know about hippos; 100% of these people believe that hippos are...*

Or maybe it's more helpful with math.

Let's say the total population of Earth is 1,000.

Sentence 1: X% of 1,000 know about hippos - it's not specified in your sentence, but let's pretend X is 10%. So, 100 people know about hippos, and 98 of those people believe that hippos are the deadliest land animal.

Sentence 2: 980 people know about hippos (98% of 1,000), and those 980 people all believe that hippos are the deadliest land animal.

Comment: I see. This was my first thought but I had doubts.. “The” meaning the numerator and the denominator being everyone in the world…Without “the” meaning only individuals in a group